# Python Checking UDP message

Tags: python, python-3.x, udp

this is my client:

```
import socket
import threading

class ThreadedServer(object):
    def __init__(self, host, port):
        self.host = host
        self.port = port
        self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        self.sock.bind((self.host, self.port))

    def listen(self):
        self.sock.listen(5)
        while True:
            client, address = self.sock.accept()
            client.settimeout(60)
            threading.Thread(target = self.listenToClient,args = (client,address)).start()

    def listenToClient(self, client, address):
        size = 1024
        while True:
            try:
                data = client.recv(size)
                if data:
                    # Set the response to echo back the recieved data 
                    response = data
                    client.send(response)
                else:
                    raise error('Client disconnected')
            except:
                client.close()
                return False

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ThreadedServer('',5000).listen()
```

I'm trying parse the message received. I have tried the following:
if data:

```
            if data == "command":
                print("Command Received")
            elif data != "command":
                response = data
                client.send(response)
        else:
            raise error('Client disconnected')
```

I have printed data to console and it comes out as `b'command'`, I have tried using that in the equal to string and it still does not print 'Command receieved' when I send it from my client which just connects to the server and sends a message doing the following `mySocket.send(message.encode())` I was wondering how I could fix my issue?

Answer (score 0):

Just found the solution: you have to decode the UDP message when printing it.

Example:

```
print data.decode()
```